# nopcommerce A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, nopcommerce-3.90

> i am working in nopcommerce solution 3.90, while importing products,
>   from excel file i get this exception. my code is as follow

```
public virtual void ImportProductsFromXlsx(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            #region Import business Logic
            using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                //get the first worksheet in the workbook
                var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();

                if (worksheet == null)
                    throw new NopException("No worksheet found");

                //the columns
                var properties = GetPropertiesByExcelCells<Product>
 (worksheet);

                var manager = new PropertyManager<Product>
 (properties);

                var attributProperties = new[]
.....
.....
 }
}
```

**StackTrace**:-

> at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.CompoundDocument.ILockBytes.WriteAt(Int64
>   ulOffset, IntPtr pv, Int32 cb, UIntPtr& pcbWritten)    at
>   OfficeOpenXml.Utils.CompoundDocument.GetLockbyte(MemoryStream stream) 
>   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Load(Stream input, Stream output, String
>   Password)    at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Load(Stream input)    at
>   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(Stream newStream)    at
>   Nop.Services.ExportImport.ImportManager.ImportProductsFromXlsx(Stream
>   stream) in
>   d:\Arsh\nop3.90\Libraries\Nop.Services\ExportImport\ImportManager.cs:line
>   330

**Solutions That i have tried are** :-

> 1. Resaving the file to be uploaded using .xlsx extension.
> 2. Using Memorystream object.
> 3. Adding name of file like(Worksheets.Add("Worksheet Name");)
> 4. Removing header text(i.e. header columns like Name, description, etc)
>
> P.S. I am using Nopcommerce. This is inbuilt code of importing
>   products.

Comment: What version of excel are you using? Have you tried exporting a small sample of products?

Comment: yes, i have done exporting as well, after exporting i got the fields in file and then i modified that file, filled the products and then i import the products that i want to insert. Version of excel file is Microsoft Office Excel 2003

Comment: And right now following this "https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5720cbfc-779a-4c5f-8d5f-6adb2fbe839b/disk-error-during-write-operaation?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Please try with excel 2010+ because earlier versions of excel differ in encrypt/decrypt algorithm.

Comment: @Ammar Thanks, it worked with Excel 2016...!!!, i would like to know more about encryption/decryption algos

Comment: I have added an answer so it may help someone who has similar problem and browsed this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with excel 2010+ because earlier versions of excel differ in encrypt/decrypt algorithm.

You can read more about encryption/decryption [here](http://www.decryptum.com/tech.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it's work;

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
await  eFile.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
package = new ExcelPackage(ms);
```